# Download Manager Sometimes Displays Unsuccessful

Tags: android, download, android-download-manager

As the title says, I have a download manager and it works but only **sometimes**. It's very weird and I can't find a pattern. I have a button which when clicked, sends a request to a server which returns the file to download, and then sometimes it downloads, sometimes it doesn't. There's not a pattern that I can see and I'm not getting any errors from the phone or the server.

This is bad for my application because I need to know it's been successfully downloaded so I either need to find out why it doesn't work sometimes, or find a way to run a function if the download fails. Here is the code I use to download the file:

```
        GlobalVariables globalVariables = new GlobalVariables();
        String url = globalVariables.getIPAddress() + "downloadsong/" + Integer.toString(songId) + "/";
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("StoredValues", MODE_PRIVATE);
        String token = sharedPreferences.getString("token", "null");

        DownloadManager downloadManager = (DownloadManager)getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
        DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));
        request.setTitle("Downloading");
        request.setDescription("Downloading new titles");
        request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
        request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC, "" + songId + ".mp3");
        request.setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI);
        request.addRequestHeader("Authorization", "Token " + token);
        request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
        request.setAllowedOverMetered(true);
        request.setAllowedOverRoaming(true);

        long downloadReference = downloadManager.enqueue(request);
        if (downloadReference != 0) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "download started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "no download started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

Any help or insight is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my example:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Button button;
private long downloadID;

private BroadcastReceiver onDownloadComplete = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        long id = intent.getLongExtra(DownloadManager.EXTRA_DOWNLOAD_ID, -1);
        if (downloadID == id) {
            validDownload(MainActivity.this, downloadID);
        }
    }
};

public void validDownload(Context context, long downloadId) {
    DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) context.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
    if (dm != null) {
        try (Cursor c = dm.query(new DownloadManager.Query().setFilterById(downloadId))) {
            if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                int status = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS));
                if (status == DownloadManager.STATUS_SUCCESSFUL) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Success", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else if (status == DownloadManager.STATUS_FAILED) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    button = findViewById(R.id.download);
    registerReceiver(onDownloadComplete, new IntentFilter(DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE));
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            DownloadManager downloadManager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
            if (downloadManager != null) {
                downloadID = downloadManager.enqueue(prepareDownloadRequest());
            }
        }
    });
}

private DownloadManager.Request prepareDownloadRequest() {
    File file = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null), "Dummy");
    DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse("http://speedtest.ftp.otenet.gr/files/test10Mb.db"))
            .setTitle("Dummy File")
            .setDescription("Downloading")
            .setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE)
            .setDestinationUri(Uri.fromFile(file))// Uri of the destination file
            .setAllowedOverMetered(true)
            .setAllowedOverRoaming(true);// Set if download is allowed on roaming networ
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
        request.setRequiresCharging(false);
    }
    return request;
}
```

}

Comment: This is just what I needed. Is there any way to restart a download based on its ID?

Answer (score 0):

You must register a broadcastreciever

```
public static int validDownload(Context context, long downloadId) {
    //Verify if download is a success
    DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) context.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
    Cursor c = dm.query(new DownloadManager.Query().setFilterById(downloadId));

    try {
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            int status = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS));

            if (status == DownloadManager.STATUS_SUCCESSFUL) {
                return 0; //Download is valid, celebrate
            } else {
                return c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_REASON));
            }
        }
    } finally {
        c.close();
    }

    return -1; 
}


private BroadcastReceiver onDownloadComplete = new BroadcastReceiver() {
   @Override
   public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

       //Fetching the download id received with the broadcast
       long id = intent.getLongExtra(DownloadManager.EXTRA_DOWNLOAD_ID, -1);

       //Checking if the received broadcast is for our enqueued download by matching download id
       if (downloadID == id) {
           validDownload(this, id);
       }

   }
```

};

And register for ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE in the onCreate method of your activity.

```
  @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    registerReceiver(onDownloadComplete, new IntentFilter(DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE));
}
```

Comment: How do I use this with the code I already have? Sorry for the trouble

Comment: Also, where do I input `downloadId`?

Comment: your `downloadReference` is the downloadId. You must register receiver and call your code.

Comment: Alright, I put in your code and I still can't figure out how to use the `BroadcastReceiver` with my `DownloadManager`. I'm getting a "cannot resolve symbol" on the `downloadId` in the onReceive override

Comment: I wrote an example for you